# sequence operations on string python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

However all other sequence operations work on strings in python

But why does the index operation throw out an error of invalid syntax?

```
  s='python sequence operation'
  s.index('s'[, 2[, 7]])
```

I see that there is a different index operation provided for strings so my assumption is that these operations are not sequence operations but specialized for strings ?

```
  s='sam'
  s[1:2]
  s.count('a')
  s*3
```

Comment: If you have a new question - then please ask it as a new question. Others have taken the time to answer what you originally asked - it's not fair to them to invalidate their answer(s) by completely changing your question.

Comment: Yep, I am happy to discuss the underlying structure of string objects, but that would be best done in a separate post.

Comment: with so many downvotes I don't think I can post new questions

Comment: "But why does the index operation throw out an error of invalid syntax?" Because it's invalid syntax. What you have written is meaningless in  Python. Left square bracket begins either a list or an index operation. Neither of those allows a comma as the very next character.

Comment: Yeah I read the documentation too literally I don't get why people here use so much of sarcasm unnecessarily

Comment: Well, the short answer of your follow-up question is, "strings and lists are completely independent, and have separate implementations for `len` and `index` etc. Neither one is implemented using the other". I can go into a little more detail if you regain the ability to post new questions.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you're trying to replicate the `S.index(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int` syntax found in the documentation for `index`. You're not supposed to actually type the square brackets. That just means those arguments are optional.

```
s.index('s', 2, 7)
```